# BufferedImage in java larger than 2^31 pixels

Tags: java, image, bufferedimage

I need to create a very large image in java and so far I've been using the java.awt.image.BufferedImage class. But it seems that this class stores it's pixels with an int as it can not go past 2^31 pixels. I've thought about creating smaller images and stitching them together, but the problem is the photo editors I try like Adobe Photoshop can't even  import photos larger than 30,000 pixels in any dimension.

I've thought about making my own image class but I am not knowledgeable enough to make everything to go into that.

Any suggestions? 
Thank You

Comment: Why does it need to be an *image*? Or could you work with an off-heap 2D buffer of some kind? You say yourself that even if you somehow managed that, it would not be usable in any program. With the available information it seems a very peculiar question. So broad it might get flagged as off-topic. If you give more details, perhaps someone could help about the custom image idea if that's really what you need (might be possible with custom `java.awt.image.{DataBuffer,Raster,...}`).

Comment: I'm creating Iterative function system images that produce a fractal like picture and I am planning on making large prints of these.

Comment: Note that even if you can get around the limitations in the Java BufferedImage class, there are still limits in image file formats. For e.g. JPEG supports a maximum of 65535 pixels in each dimension, and TIFF has a max 4Gb file size. What format are you intending to supply to the printer?

Comment: depending on how your drawing function works, and if draws one line at a time from top to bottom, you could simply draw each line and write it directly to disk. this could be a raw RBG format which you then processes with something else into another image format.

Comment: Does it have to be a `BufferedImage`? The `BufferedImage` class is usually backed by a single array, making Java array size limitations more of an issue, rather than physical memory. You could experiment with custom `DataBuffer` implementations though. I would also look into the `RenderedImage` interface, which supports tiles, if you are able to work on regions of the image at a time.

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably struggle to load an image of that size memory because the memory footprint of an image of 2^31 x 1px would be:

```
2^31px * 1px * 4 bytes/px = 4,294,967,296 bytes = ~4.2 GB
```

A 2^31px x 4px image would already consume more memory than most computers have. Stitching the images together is the correct design for such a situation. A simple solution would be to keep a multidimensional array of images and load them in and out of memory based on your requirements.

[ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/) is a mature utility for processing images, and it can support very large image sizes. Since you say you want to write a large image file, I would suggest using the [montage feature](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/montage/). Render parts of your fractal and save them to disk, then once rendering is finished, invoke the ImageMagick montage command from your program to generate the final large file.

Comment: I'm running a workstation with 32GB so that isn't my problem yet. How would you write the images to a single image file?

Comment: Personally I would use ImageMagick because writing this yourself will likely be difficult. Especially when you have to deal with image file formats and trying to progressively build a large image file. Take a look at the montage feature of ImageMagick. http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/montage/  You would write each part of the fractal to disk and then use ImageMagick at the end to produce the complete file.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that GIMP is able to import photos that are 2^31 or less in any dimension so I'm able to stitch together photos with this. Thank you to everyone that responded.